# Which approach is better to communicate from WebApplicaiton to JavaApplication?

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, web

I have JavaApplication that when it starts it opens socket and listen to connection (like server).
I also have WebApplication that should take some data from the JavaApplication and display it in WebBrowser. To implement this I thought to:

1. using Servlet I can connect to that JavaApplication using socket and get the data
2. create WebService: WebApplication will send request to WebService and WebService will open socket and connect to the JavaApplication.
3. your approach

All this located in the same server.

Does second approach looks way over because eventually I open socket so I can do it from Servlet and not talking to WebService in the middle?

Comment: I think this depends on your needs... and if you actually don't plan to expose various features in the future from your java app, web service would probably be an overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no answer to this question - there is simply no information to base this decision on.

Writing a web service is a lot of work, so approach #1 would avoid "useless" work. On the other hand, it would make the Java service available to other uses because other applications (or even other web services) could use the web service to talk to it.

So if this work will be useful for others as well, implement it as a web service. That would also allow you to deploy the web service on its own, so access to the java app wouldn't depend on whether your web app is running or not.

Comment: +1. YAGNI and so forth - never implement what isn't needed, pure waste.

Comment: I implemented the 1st approach because I used only for my needs

Answer (score 0):

IMO, if you want to do this "right" you should plan on implementing it in at least two ways.  To do so this you should then have to define your "service" in the Java Application independently of the communication mechanism you are going to subsequently use.

Once that service interface is defined, you need to pick the two ways you are going to use from a rather large set of possibilities:

- Files
- database table
- raw sockets
- JMS
- AMQP
- web sockets
- SOAP based web service
- RESTful web service
- Many others, but you get the point

As noted in another reply, there is no universal "right" choice.  The decision will be dictated by the specifics of the problem you are solving.   Once you have picked two possibilites, you implement the best candidate of those two.   If you actually really need the second one, you can implement that as well, or just save it for later, knowing that your design will easily accomodate such growth :)

Answer (score 0):

First, is there any possibility of integrating the "Server" Java code directly? Make a callable library?

Second, what's the relationship between requests to your servlet and fetches of data from the server? Do you get different data for each request?

Generally I wouldn't fancy opening and closing sockets for talking to the server for each request - seems more like a case for a pool of such connections.

My instinct, knowing little about your requirements. Write a thread-safe java component that opens a socket and gets some data. Have a pool of such objects that the servlet requests can grab use and return to the pool.

Java EE has some restrictions about what is permitted in servlets and EJBs, your app server might have some "Worker" concept, from which you actually make the use of the connector object.